# Java regular expression to match parameters within a function

Tags: java, regex, parameters

I would like to write a regular expression to extract `parameter1` and `parameter2` of `func1(parameter1, parameter2)`, the length of `parameter1` and `parameter2` ranges from 1 to 64.

```
(func1) (\() (.{1,64}) (,\\s*) (.{1,64}) (\))
```

My version can not deal with the following case (nested function)

```
func2(func1(ef5b, 7dbdd))
```

I always get a "7dbdd)" for `parameter2`. How could I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[^)]{1,64}` (match all except `)`) instead of `.{1,64}` (match any) to stop right before the first `)`

```
(func1) (\() (.{1,64}) (,\\s*) (.{1,64}) (\))
                                ^
                                replace . with [^)]
```

Example:

```
// remove whitespace and escape backslash!
String regex = "(func1)(\\()(.{1,64})(,\\s*)([^)]{1,64})(\\))";
String input = "func2(func1(ef5b, 7dbdd))";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex); // java.util.regex.Pattern
Matcher m = p.matcher(input); // java.util.regex.Matcher
if(m.find()) { // use while loop for multiple occurrences
    String param1 = m.group(3);
    String param2 = m.group(5);

    // process the result...
}
```

If you want to ignore whitespace tokens, use this one:

```
func1\s*\(\s*([^\s]{1,64})\s*,\s*([^\s\)]{1,64})\s*\)"
```

Example:

```
// escape backslash!
String regex = "func1\\s*\\(\\s*([^\\s]{1,64})\\s*,\\s*([^\\s\\)]{1,64})\\s*\\)";
String input = "func2(func1 ( ef5b, 7dbdd ))";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex); // java.util.regex.Pattern
Matcher m = p.matcher(input); // java.util.regex.Matcher
if(m.find()) { // use while loop for multiple occurrences
    String param1 = m.group(1);
    String param2 = m.group(2);

    // process the result...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use "anything but closing parenthesis" (`[^)]`) instead of simply "anything" (`.`):

```
(func1) (\() (.{1,64}) (,\s*) ([^)]{1,64}) (\))
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/sP6eS1/1

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helpful

```
func1[^\(]*\(\s*([^,]{1,64}),\s*([^\)]{1,64})\s*\)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(func1) (\() (.{1,64}) (,\\s*) ([^)]{1,64}) (\))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^.*(func1)(\()(.{1,64})(,\s*)(.{1,64}[A-Za-z\d])(\))+
```

Working example: [here](https://regex101.com/r/aQ5eR7/1)